# LabVIEW - How to clear an array after each iteration in a for loop

Tags: labview

[image]I'm trying to clear an array after each iteration of a for loop in LabVIEW, but the way I've implemented it has the values not going directly to what I want, but it changes with previous values in other parts of the array.

It isn't shown, but this code is inside of a for-loop that iterates through another numeric array.

I know that if I get the array to clear properly after each loop iteration, this should work. How do I do that? I'm a beginner at Labview but have been coding for awhile - help is appreciated!!!

[![labview add to array][2]][2]

Comment: Can you post the full code? At least the full for loop and the array indexing it

Comment: Moreover, wht do you exactly mena for "cleaning the array"?

Comment: @SilentCloud just uploaded the full code - I made some changes to see if it would work, but the revision doesn't work either. I mean "clearing" just like making the array back to what it was originally before I added elements to it. Kind of like array2 = 0 essentially at the start of each loop

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you're not quite used to how LabVIEW passes data around yet. There's no need to use lots of value property nodes for the same control or indicator within one structure; if you want to use the same data in more than one place, just branch the wire. Perhaps you're thinking that a LabVIEW control or indicator is equivalent to a variable in text languages, and you need to use a property node to get or set it. Instead, think of the **wire** as the variable. If you want to pass the output of one operation to the input of another, just wire the output to the input.

The indicators with terminals inside your loop will be updated with new values every loop iteration, and the code inside the loop should execute faster than a human can read those values, so once the loop has finished all the outputs except the final values will be lost. Is that what you intended, or do you want to accumulate or store them in some way?

I can see that in each loop iteration you're reading two values from a config file, and the section is specified by the string value of one element of the numeric array `Array`. You're displaying the two values in the indicators `PICKERING` and `SUBUNIT`. If you can describe in words (or pseudocode, or a text language you're used to) what manipulation of data you're actually trying to do in the rest of this code, we may be able to make more specific suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm assuming that the desired order of operations is the following:

1. Putting the value of `Pickering` into `Array 2`
2. Extracting from `Array 2` the values to put in `Pickering 1` and `Pickering 2`
3. Putting `Array 2` back to its original value

If this is the case, with your current code you can't be sure that operation `1` will be executed be fore operation `2`. In fact, the order of these operations can't be pre-determined. You must force the dataflow, for example by creating a `sequence structure`. You will put the code related to `1` in the first frame, then code related to operation `2` in the second.
Then, to put `Array 2` back to it's original value I would add a third frame, where you force an empty array into the `Value` property node of `Array 2` (the tool you use for pickering, but as input and not as output).
The `sequence structure` has to be inside the `for loop`.

I have never used the property node `Reinit to default`, so I can't help you with that.

Unfortunately I can't run Labview on this PC but I hope my explanation was clear enough, if not tell me and I will try to be more specific.

Comment: The `Reinit To Default` method resets the control or indicator to its default value, which you can change by right-clicking on it and choosing `Data Operations` > `Make Current Value Default` - that will then be the setting of the control when you open the VI, and/or if the control is unwired when it's in a subVI. I don't think this is what the asker really wants to do though.

Comment: Also while you're right to point out that the asker's code will execute in indeterminate order, I don't think the solution to this is to start using sequence structures - I think they should simply use wires for passing data.